# How to keep data temporary somewhere and using the same to store it in database every 10 minutes?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, design-patterns

I want to **solve** one of my **design problem** where I am getting several events data but for one kind of data I do not want to store the event as soon as it happens instead I want to wait for 10 minutes to let them happen those event but want to keep the number of event counts happening so that once the interval of 10 minutes reaches I can store the count with the event cumulatively which will reduce the number of operation being involve with database.

**For example**
Let's say I have three events namely **EV1**, **EV2** and **EV3**. Event **EV3** happens in my application in very large volume other two events are less frequent. But I am not concerns to capture every trigger of the event but I am interested to know how many times that event (EV3) happened. So thinking to capture the EV3 count in 10 minute of interval by storing the counts somewhere on the fly and dump the same in every 10 minutes.

**Please suggest a good and simple design for it which can be used in Java, Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use caching to store your data temporarily(like Redis) and then save the data to your db. Not sure what your event is but   this is general design followed to store data temporarily and reduce db writes.

Comment: To find cumulative sum number of events , you can write another script and execute it in parallel, to fetch data from cache and find sum.Not sure that it's the best way though

Comment: Your answer may redirect me to think towards a better solution. Thanks, but still looking for a  solution which can solve it in better way.

Comment: 'Better' is very subjective , what exactly are you trying to improve ?You have not specified what exactly are you doing currently , what is the event (is it from a single client or multiple client), is it shared etc.:You need to be more articulate in your question for an exact answer

Comment: This answer redirected me for a solution.